# Calling PHP via a HTML anchor on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am currently reading through a piece of code provided by my faculty and I am having troubles understanding how it works.
Specifically how the anchor is linked to the php without method="post" or method="get".
Kindly appreciate if anyone could explain or link me to relevant materials to do further readings. Much thanks.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
if (isset($_GET['buy'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_GET['buy'];
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?' . SID);
    exit();
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($items); $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$items[$i]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>$" .number_format($prices[$i], 2). "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='" .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?buy=' .$i. "'>Buy</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: The query string variable in the `href` - `?buy=` - can be picked up with `$_GET['buy']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cart for bought items indexes is created in session if it's not there yet.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
```

When link with **buy** query parameter is opened, **buy** value is added to session cart. After that page is redirected to location without **buy** parameter.

```
if (isset($_GET['buy'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_GET['buy'];
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?' . SID);
    exit();
}
```

List of items to buy is printed on page (i quess code in question is not full).

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($items); $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$items[$i]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>$" .number_format($prices[$i], 2). "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='" .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?buy=' .$i. "'>Buy</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

1. Links open pages with GET method.
2. Link query parameters can be accessed by special $_GET variable